# Not sure what to do with these errors on User Dashboard

Tags: user-dashboard, version

I have wordpress redirect users that login to their User Dashboard. When I login as an administrator I always get the following error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/VersionCheck.php on line 429

Warning: file_get_contents(https://latest.civicrm.org/stable.php?format=json): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/VersionCheck.php on line 429
```

Any idea what this is about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
 https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0
```

suggests to change **allow_url_fopen = 1**  in **php.ini** file on your hosting server.

Comment: This did it!  Thank you!  I wonder what other settings in my PHP settings are incorrect. :) Can I award you Karma? Not sure how this works.

Comment: Glad it helped! re: karma - yes, please, have no idea  how it works either though :-)